# PHP Laravel Migrate to vps faild

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working to migrate a Laravel application, and the dependencies were installed and everything is running fine.

The problem is that sometimes ajax requests are accepted by the server and sometimes it gives me an error (500).

This is the error message:

```
Undefined variable: errors (View: /home/apps/apps/plat/resources/views/layouts/layout.blade.php) (View: /home/apps/apps/plat/resources/views/layouts/layout.blade.php)
```

The error is on line 153 and this is the code

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

I thought it might be a problem of versions, since in 1and1 it uses version 7.1 and it works perfectly, but install the same version and it doesn't work. I don't see anything weird in this part of code, but it's where it fails

If anyone has found or knows any suggestions / solutions I would greatly appreciate them.

Comment: why dont you check your logs so you can see what the error is?

Comment: Check your logs, I recommend to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs and laravel logs (storage/logs) to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Wherever you pass errors to the view, check you actually HAVE errors, if not, pass an empty array and this error message will disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this once, it might not be perfect solution but you can avoid the Undefined variable error you are getting currently

```
@if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

@endif

Answer (score 1):

`count($errors) > 0` expects `$errors` to be defined. Use `!empty` instead so that it will check for both undefined and empty errors

```
@if (!empty($errors))
```